# toctree entry pointing to non reST files

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I have built some HTML files with javadoc. I have those in Sphinx `_static` dir. Now I'm trying to put a link to those HTML files in Sphinx `toctree`:

```
.. toctree::

    API reference <_static/api/index.html>
```

Is there any way to do this? As much as I've tried Sphinx only accepts reST files in `toctree`.